# How to open a different URL for each block on listview builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a very simple Flutter app that shows the user four tiles. When the user clicks on one of the tiles, the app is supposed to open the URL in their browser that corresponds to that tile. For example, if the tile says "YouTube" then when that tile is pressed the app should take the user to YouTube. I have got something working but it doesn't work as intended. When you click on one of the tiles it doesn't take you to the desired website, it takes you to one of the other websites that I am trying to open within the app. For example, if you click on the tile that says Covid-19 Cases, the app opens Dr. John Campbell's YouTube Channel. I think my problem lies in the for loop in the _launchUrl method, but I am not sure how to fix it. I hope my explanation wasn't too long. I would appreciate suggestion from anyone, thank you all so much!
I will attach the code and a screen shot of the app.
I am not allowed to show pictures on my posts yet. I hope the URL isn't too much trouble.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  List<String> titles = \["Covid-19 Cases", "Covid-19 Vaccine Tracker",
    "Dr. John Campbell Youtube Channel", "Medcram YouTube Channel"\];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          title: Text("Your Covid-19 Briefing"),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: titles.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  _launchUrl(index);
                },
                title: Text(
                  titles\[index\],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    letterSpacing: 1.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

// try assigning a number to each element. Then using
  _launchUrl(index) async {
    List<String> _urlsToLaunch = List(4);
    _urlsToLaunch\[0\] = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/";
    _urlsToLaunch\[1\] = "https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/science/coronavirus-vaccine-tracker.html";
    _urlsToLaunch\[2\] = "https://www.youtube.com/c/Campbellteaching/videos/";
    _urlsToLaunch\[3\] = "https://www.youtube.com/c/Medcram/videos";

    for(int i=0; i<_urlsToLaunch.length; i++) {
      if (await canLaunch(_urlsToLaunch\[i\])) {
        await launch(_urlsToLaunch\[i\]);
      } else {
        throw "Could not open $_urlsToLaunch";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You do not need `for loop` 
code snippet

```
_launchUrl(index) async {
    if (await canLaunch(_urlsToLaunch[index])) {
      await launch(_urlsToLaunch[index]);
    } else {
      throw "Could not open $_urlsToLaunch";
    }
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> titles = [
    "Covid-19 Cases",
    "Covid-19 Vaccine Tracker",
    "Dr. John Campbell Youtube Channel",
    "Medcram YouTube Channel"
  ];

  List<String> _urlsToLaunch = [
    "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/",
    "https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/science/coronavirus-vaccine-tracker.html",
    "https://www.youtube.com/c/Campbellteaching/videos/",
    "https://www.youtube.com/c/Medcram/videos"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          title: Text("Your Covid-19 Briefing"),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: titles.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    _launchUrl(index);
                  },
                  title: Text(
                    titles[index],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      letterSpacing: 1.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  _launchUrl(index) async {
    if (await canLaunch(_urlsToLaunch[index])) {
      await launch(_urlsToLaunch[index]);
    } else {
      throw "Could not open $_urlsToLaunch";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer very helpful. I can't believe the solution was as simple as deleting the for loop. Thanks again!